# How to sum the Group totals only?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I'm trying to sum only group HourTarget totals.

```
          7:00     8:00    HourTarget    
Line 1    2715     1008      3224
  A       2307     1008      3224 
  B       408        0       3224
Line 2    2308     2432      2656
  A       2308     2432      2656
Line 3    2318     1622      2800
  A       345      1258      2800
  B       762        0       2800
  C       1211     364       2800
```

I'm trying to achieve 8680 as a result of sum of HourTarget. But I'm getting 17504. It is because HourTarget in a database table is record for every single product running on this line, but the target is related to the line and not the product. How can I sum only the Group total?

Something like this is not working:

```
=Sum(Max(Fields!HourTarget.Value))
```

Comment: Is this specifically SSRS 2008 and not 2008R2?

Comment: it is 2008R2, sorry for confusing

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Since you are on SSRS 2008R2, you can use the aggregate of aggregate functionality that was added in that version.

You were on the right track; you just need to add a **Scope** value to your expression.

I'm using a version of your data, and have constructed a simple tablix:

[image]

[image]

Note that I have created a group called *Line*.

To get the `Sum` of the `Max` *HourTarget* column, use the expression:

```
=Sum(Max(Fields!HourTarget.Value,  "Line"))
```

This works out the `Max` for each *Line* group, then takes the `Sum` of these.

Now we have your required value:

[image]

Prior to SSRS 2008R2 there was no easy way to do this; typically one would add an extra column to the DataSet with the pre-aggregated value to display in the report.

Comment: It is working very well, thank you. How would I use the sum of HourTarget for conditional formatting? When total of 7:00 is greater or equal Sum of HourTarget is green else red. I tried this one but I get error that it is not in the group. =IIF(Sum(Fields!HourCount.Value) >= Sum(Max(Fields!HourTarget.Value,  "LineID")), "LimeGreen", "Red")

Comment: Ok, I figure it out. If someone need it I have used: ReportItems![Text Box name].Value

Comment: Cool, was just typing a reply. At the table header level your first approach should be OK (and seemed to work OK for me in a quick test) but yours is also a great way, especially if it works for you!

Comment: Could you merge **Hour Target** rows for each group ?

Answer (score 1):

`( Sum(CDbl(Fields!Field_1.Value))`  is working .

[image]