# How can I sum only the visible rows in RDLC Report

Tags: .net, rdlc

I have the data from the database in the following format

```
Name Amount Outstanding
C-1   100    20
C-1   100    10
C-1   100    40
--------------------------
Total 300    70
```

I have a RDLC Report that generates the report in the below given way:

```
Name Amount Outstanding
C-1   100    20
             10
             40
--------------------------
Total 300    70
```

However I want the data to be displayed as

```
Name Amount Outstanding
C-1   100    20
             10
             40
--------------------------
Total 100    70
```

I have applied the expression as `=Sum(Fields!Amount.Value)`

Any solution regarding this issue?

Comment: `=Max(Fields!Amount.Value)` or even just `=Fields!Amount.Value` should be OK.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677960/how-to-sum-the-group-totals-only

Answer (score 0):

Use the same condition that you are using to toggle visibility in your sum function:

```
SUM(IIF(<your visible = true condition>, Fields!Amount.Value, 0))
```

Comment: There is no visibility condition that I have applied. I have only grouped the rows.

Comment: Ah, so you are just suppressing duplicate values then. I assumed you have some visibility condition based on the title of your question. Then using Max function like Ian suggested is your answer.

Comment: By grouping only, the rows become hidden. But data is still there. I have not specified explicitly any visibility condition. Using Max wont work because I have only provided one group here, but in reality there are multiple groups and I have to show their grand total also.

Answer (score 0):

Add Values as Amount and Expression as

```
=Sum(int(Fields!Outstanding.Value))
```

And Add Category Groups as Name

Comment: Can you please explain why this will help OP with their issue?