# SSRS Summing a group average

Tags: sum, ssrs-2008, grouping, average

I need to sum the averages within row groups in SSRS 2008 and have not found a solution I can work with.

Required output:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated; I have tried several custom code options, including:

```
public dim totals as int32 = 0

public function Setavg( value As int32)
    totals = totals + value
    return value
end function
```

(This one aggregates the subtotal values within the group)

Comment: This question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677960/how-to-sum-the-group-totals-only

Comment: Thanks you but i am using SSRS 2008 not the R2 version where this solution works.