# SSRS SUM of Header rows

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping, dynamics-365

I know there are a number of similar questions on here which I've looked at but I can't quite find one the same as my particular issue.

I have the following report built in SSRS (looking at a Dynamics 365 instance, so I believe SSRS version is 2016 but if not then it should be modern), and the yellow fields at the bottom are supposed to be a sum of the blue header rows throughout the rest of the report, but as you can see they are incorrect. I am using exactly the same syntax as I am for the other fields in white on the row that do sum correctly, so I don't understand why it's only these 3 I'm having issues with.

[image: Report]

I have the following 2 groups set up:

[image]

The expression for my Budget Days sum is simply:
`=FormatNumber((SUM(Fields!task_msdyn_effortValue.Value)/8),2)`

The other fields are the same concept, a simple sum of the values. Based on another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21677960/how-to-sum-the-group-totals-only), I tried adding in the name of the ProjectTask group to the expression as I believe it's summing up all the rows in the report but this gives an error about scope so perhaps my group is set up incorrectly?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: what does the expression SUM(Fields!task_msdyn_effortValue.Value) give you for the Budget Days? forget the formatting and dividing etc.. does it add up correctly?

Comment: Do you have any filters applied to any of the groups?